# Changing the ImageUrl property dynamically (C#)

Tags: c#

How can I Change the ImageUrl property dynamically (C#)

Comment: do you mean changing it by javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "your image path";
```

sets the location of the image with name Image1.

Read

[ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx)

Eg:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImageName.gif";
```